# Hadoop benchmarking/Performance testing

Tags: hadoop, benchmarking, performance-testing

I want to perform benchmarking and Performance testing on my Hadoop cluster.
I know hadoop-mapreduce*test*.jar and hadoop-mapreduce-examples*.jar has many programs for benchmarking.

Are there any documents available for these tests which gives details for test and performance measures for each?
Also, after performing any test, are there any values available to compare the results?

Thanks.

Comment: The most popular benchmark for Hadoop clusters performance is Tera byte sort I think.

Answer (score 9):

You have HiBench which contains some tool for benchmarking hdfs, hive ... You can find it here : https://github.com/intel-hadoop/HiBench

Berkeley university created a benchmark with a dataset for hive, impala ... You can refer to it here : https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/benchmark/

Terasort is a famous benchmark too. It contains 3 programs which generate data and use MapReduce to test your cluster. More information here : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/package-summary.html